# Add class from child to each parent with jQuery each and addClass

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html

```
<div class="blog-posts">    
  <div class="post"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-blog"></span></div>
  <div class="post"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-snippet"></span></div>
  <div class="post"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-code"></span></div>
  <div class="post"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-blog"></span></div> 
</div>
```

and following css classes

```
.post {height:30px;border:2px solid}    
.post.article-blog {background:red}
.post.article-code {background:blue}
.post.article-snippet {background:green}
```

i want to add to each **post** the class specifed by the child

```
<span class="ptype" data-type="article-blog"></span>
```

i'm using jquery like this but it just takes the class from first child and applies to to all parents

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post").each(function(index, value) {
        var ptype = $(".ptype").attr("data-type");
        console.log(ptype);
        $(".post").addClass(ptype);
    });
});
```

Any hints? here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2gbqban/)

This is the html i'm trying to get

```
<div class="blog-posts">    
  <div class="post article-blog"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-blog"></span></div>
  <div class="post article-snippet"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-snippet"></span></div>
  <div class="post article-code"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-code"></span></div>
  <div class="post article-blog"><span class="ptype" data-type="article-blog"></span></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: find `.ptype` which is child of `this` - `var ptype = $(this).find(".ptype").attr("data-type")`

Comment: there are several other parents around the child

Comment: I would appreciate if someone would give the "basic" answer instead of just down voting the question. I'm new with coding (see my SO rep!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

```
$(".post").each(function(index, value) {
    var ptype = $(".ptype").attr("data-type"); // mistake 1
    console.log(ptype);
    $(".post").addClass(ptype);                // mistake 2
});
```

**Mistake 1**: this selector selects **all** `.ptype` elements. And you need `.ptype` element which is child of current `.post`. This can be done this way:

```
var ptype = $(this).find(".ptype").attr("data-type");
```

**Mistake 2**: this selector selects **all** `.post` elements and applies class to them. But you need only current `.post` element. This again can be done with `this`

```
$(this).addClass(ptype);
```

Finally, the proper code is:

```
 $(".post").each(function(index, value) {
    var ptype = $(this).find(".ptype").attr("data-type");
    console.log(ptype);
    $(this).addClass(ptype);
});
```

And to simplify:

```
 $(".post").each(function(index, value) {
    $( this ).addClass( $( this ).find( ".ptype" ).attr( "data-type" ) );
});
```